Add histogram graphic within gaussian bell
My idea is to recreate this image

The Gaussian curve worked well. What I can't do is the histogram. I would just need to recreate just one step, then I can do the rest based on the trend of the curve
This is the MWE:
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \scalebox{1} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
            mark=none,domain=-3:3,samples=50,smooth}, width=10cm, %xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, clip mode=individual,
            % All plots: from -2:2, 50 samples, smooth, no marks
            axis x line*=bottom, % no box around the plot, only x and y axis
            axis y line*=left, % the * suppresses the arrow tips
            enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top;
        \addplot[black, fill=lightgray, hist] plot coordinates { (-2, 0.1) (-2, 0.2) };
        \addplot {gauss(0,1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
enlargelimits=upper,
]
\addplot[ybar, bar width=6/15, fill=lightgray, domain=-3:3, samples=16] {gauss(0,1)};
\addplot[mark=none, domain=-3:3, samples=50, smooth] {gauss(0,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


